# setInterval ускоряется

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
    function click(){
        console.log('hi');
    }
    setInterval(click, 1000)
    clearInterval(click)
});
```

Когда нажимаю на кнопку несколько раз, выполняет за 1 секунду по несколько раз. В чем проблема?

Comment: вы несколько интервалов запускаете: это же очевидно) и очищаете не то что нужно

Comment: А как это сделать?

Comment: setInterval присвоить переменной) что бы потом можно было его очистить

Comment: Когда я ему присваиваю переменную : var inter = setInterval(click, 1000)
    clearInterval(inter), функция не работает(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас несколько ошибок:

> когда нажимаю на кнопку несколько раз, выполняет за 1 секунду по несколько раз.

Потому что каждый раз при клике создаете новый интервал

```
clearInterval(click)
```

Функция `clearInterval` принимает id  интервала, а не функцию + вызывая сразу после создания интервала, у вас бы он ни разу не вызвался, так как сразу бы удалился

```
function click(){
    console.log('hi');
}
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    // this ссылается на текущий элемент
    if (this.clicked) {
        this.clicked = false;
        clearInterval(this.clickInterval);
    } else {
        // Сохраним флаг и интервал в св-ва конкретной кнопки
        this.clicked = true;
        this.clickInterval = setInterval(click, 1000);
    }
});
```

Либо, если нужно просто один раз вызвать обработчик, то используйте `one`

```
$('.button').one('click', function () {}); // вызовется только один раз
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает)

Answer (score 1):

`clearInterval(click)` — это по сути то же самое, что и

```
clearInterval(function (){
  console.log('hi');
})
```

`clearInterval` должен получить в качестве аргумента не функцию, 

а результат вызова функции `setInterval`. А что же он возвращает?

```js
let interval = setInterval( function(){
  console.log( interval );
}, 1000 );

let bubu = setInterval( function(){
  console.log( bubu );
}, 1000 );
```

Сам не знал, а оказывается это просто число) Все запущенные интервалы где-то сохраняются под номером, а setInterval возвращает этот номер. clearInterval может взять номер и удалить то, что под ним сохранено.

```js
let interval;

$('.button').on('click', function() {
  clearInterval( interval ); // Удалить ПЕРЕД запуском нового интервала.
  interval = setInterval(hi, 1000);
  // Если очистить интервал тут, сразу после запуска - он просто не сработает.
});

function hi() {
  console.log('hi');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="button">button</button>
```